# Sliding Window: Efficiently Calculating the Cumulative Maximum

Tags: performance, matlab, sliding-window

I have a two-dimensional matrix `A`, where each column represents a time-series.

For each time-series, I need to calculate the cumulative maximum of each window of length `k`:

```
RESULT = nan(size(A));
% loop over each time-series.
for col = 1:size(A, 2)
    % loop over the elements of the time-series (excluding the first 'k-1' elements).
    for row = k:size(A, 1)
        % extract the sliding window.
        window = A((row-k+1):row, col);
        % calculate the cumulative maximum of that sliding window.
        cumax_vector = cummax(window);
        % do something with it.
        RESULT(row,col) = ...;
    end
end
```

I realize that extracting a sliding `window` for each element of `A` and subsequently calculating the vector containing its cumulative maximum is very inefficient.

Is there a way to do that more efficiently?

Comment: it seem you need maximum over each window, not cumulative maximum, is it correct?

Comment: @Hadi No, I actually need the cumulative maximum.

Comment: if you calculate cumulative maximum on each loop iteration the you need a 3d matrix to store all values, (in each loop iteration it generates a 2d matrix of cumulative sum)

Comment: @Hadi Yes. Unfortunately my 2d matrix is already so big that there's no way i can do that without running out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could rearrange matrix A and calculate cummax on new matrix,
to do that you should first create an index matrix (C) then calculate cummax(A(C))

i demonstrated the method with following example, for simplicity i assumed that A is 5x1 matrix and k=3
for 2d A matrix you could loop on A's column or you could simply create a 3d index matrix ad so on.

```
>> A=rand(5,1)

A =

0.6557
0.0357
0.8491
0.9340
0.6787

>> C=ones(3,3).*(1:3)'+(0:1:2)

C =

 1     2     3
 2     3     4
 3     4     5

>> A(C)

ans =

0.6557    0.0357    0.8491
0.0357    0.8491    0.9340
0.8491    0.9340    0.6787

>> cummax(A(C))

ans =

0.6557    0.0357    0.8491
0.6557    0.8491    0.9340
0.8491    0.9340    0.9340
```

Edit 1:
if you haven't enough memory to calculate whole A at once you could calculate index matrix and slice it ,then calulate cummax on each slice. in a loop. after each iteration you should write results on a file and clear variables to free memory.

Comment: Yeah that's a smart way to do it...awesome, thanks a lot!